# TeamCity "Choose VCS roots to label" disabled

Tags: git, teamcity

I am attempting to configure TeamCity to work with a Git repository. I would like to label each successful build. However under the "Version Control Settings" tab "VCS Labeling section" the option "Choose VCS roots to label" is disabled. In the past I was able to check this option -- but after adding a new VCS root the option is now disabled for both regardless of whether I keep the roots attached or not. To be honest I'm not exactly sure what steps I took before enabled the checkbox, so I'm hoping someone in the community can help me out!

[image: VCS Labeling Not Working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it takes a few steps. You cannot choose the VCS because you have *"Do not label"* selected.

1. Change *"Do not label"* to *"Successful only"* or *"Always"*
2. Click save
3. After clicking save, your VCS checkbox *"BitBucket"* will be enabled.

*Note that the pattern is the same if you do use templates in the future, except that you need to make those changes on the template instead.*

Comment: Thanks that was it -- I had tried selecting "Do not label" but not saving the change then refreshing...

Answer (score 0):

Did you attach the VCS in an underlying template, or on the build definition itself?

Comment: I'm not using any build configuration templates if I follow you. There is only a one build configuration at the moment.